# PrimeNG: p-autoComplete not clearing value

Tags: html, angularjs, primeng

I am using PrimeNG. I wrote code for auto-complete as follows

```
<p-autoComplete name="searchSuggestions" [(ngModel)]="suggestion" 
(completeMethod)="searchSuggestions($event)" [suggestions]="searchSuggestionsResult" field="field"></p-autoComplete>
```

I am clearing `suggestion` in a method, but not clearing autocomplete input value. It's clearing only if I select from suggestions.

```
this.suggestion = undefined;
```

Comment: am using this same. but it's working for mine :( you want to clear selected value or needs to clear all suggestions?

Comment: Not both, wanna clear garbage value I typed

Comment: But `this.suggestion = undefined;` this code doing that for myside. can you add it in jsfiddle?

Comment: I am using IE. Fine in IE for u?

Comment: am using IE edge. may be you need update the  `primng` version

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. yes on upgrade it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly upgrade your `primeng` version up to `"primeng": "^1.1.1"`, then this will work as well.

Comment: I am using with npm 4.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Use onClear() method & set your model values = null.

====HTML

```
(onClear)="clearValue()
```

==ts

```
clearValue()
{
    this.suggestion = null;
}
```

This function will get called only when you are cleared all the values from auto-complete list.

Hope this will work!!

Comment: Bizarre that by default the control does not bind null/undefined/empty string when the value is cleared.